# Retrieving image fields by user from database 

Tags: 7

I am creating a custom module for user specific image gallery for my website. I have created a content type and added an image field for uploading multiple images. Now I want to create an image gallery with jcarousel type slideshow. But I am not able to retrieve the images uploaded by a particular user and show them on their profile page creating a gallery tab

Answer (score 1):

I did it for this cg related image gallery ([cgart.ir](http://cgart.ir)).

to display user created images on his/her profile I did these steps:

1. create a views named `artworks`
2. create a display within `artworks` named `page_1` and add `CONTEXTUAL FILTERS > (content: Author uid)` to it
3. edit `user-profile.tpl.php` and add below codes to it:

   print views_embed_view('artworks', 'page_1', $account->uid);

Answer (score 0):

The other way around is to use the 'PWI' - Picasa Webalbum Integrator javascript library. [Picasa Webalbum Integrator javascript library](http://code.google.com/p/pwi/)which fetches photos from your picasa account + it also comes with an slideshow, which applies everywhere on the site. Which is good as it also saves hosting space.